# How bright would the Earth be at night without the moon?

Tags: visible-light, earth, moon

How bright would the Earth be at night without the moon? Specifically, how much light would reach the surface of the Earth at sea level?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand how the question differs from the usual monthly new moon phase?

Comment: Depends on whether the sky is cloudy or not. Under a cloudy sky it's pretty dark.

Comment: @CuriousOne well, your comment certainly brightened my day

Comment: @AcidJazz: I am glad to have brought light to this shady matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every month there is a new moon. The moon isn't visible on this day. You've seen it before. That's how dark it would be.

Comment: That's a good point, although we still get light from the sun, even during a new moon.

Comment: So go outside on an _overcast_ new moon night, and see. :-)